# pan gesture and swipe gesture

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

In my project I need a swipe gesture action for left right movement and I need a pan gesture action for top bottom directions. When I put both gestures, only pan gesture is invoking. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToPreviosSong)];
rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToNextSong)];
rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];
```

for pan i'm using this code

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panAction:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:edgePanGesture];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[panGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:rightSwipe];
[panGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:leftSwipe];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` to recognize the gesture if the other gesture recognizer did not executes.

```
[rightSwipe requireGestureRecognizerToFail: panGesture];
[leftSwipe requireGestureRecognizerToFail: panGesture];
```